# Safety concerns and precautions in setting up a workshop/studio in the utility room

Tags: basement, safety

I am considering setting up a workspace/studio in my utility room in the basement, which has a hot water tank and two furnaces. Here are the warnings on those units.

Hot water tank:
[image]
[image]
[image]

Furnaces:
[image]
[image]

I wonder if this is a good idea in general to set up a workspace in the utility room. Is it a risky move? Any advice, safety concerns or precautions should be considered or put in place? For example, I am thinking about adding a carbon monoxide detector in the utility room to give an earlier warning in case of CO leak.

Edit:
I am planning to use it for, say, art projects, building model gundam figures etc, and/or building robotic projects. I am also open to suggestion of what this room should be used for if those projects put it in higher risk. I just want to better use the space if possible.

Comment: What are you going to do in the workspace? I wouldn't use oil based paints near an open flame.

Comment: I have added more detail in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any cause for concern with your intended use of the area. However, things don't always work out like we plan.

Therefore, a double-the-capacity Bath Exhaust Fan, Exterior Wall Fan or even a kitchen Range-hood (to be down much closer to your work...can be mounted to slide up and down) would be ideal.

Such an exhaust can be switched on and off only as needed and can act quickly to the demand. The installation of an Exhaust Fan intends to flow clean air past the furnaces and water heater as your fumes and dust exit the house while never coming near those appliances.

Yes, an Exhaust Fan can create a negative pressure scenario that could possibly draw CO from those appliances, but most homes leak enough air for that not to happen. Just keep your workspace Exhaust Fan, if you choose to install one, within a finite ability.